# Sage CRM - Field with entry type 53 (Territory) is not available when creating a new field?

Tags: sage-crm

Im trying to create a field in the team entity to be able to select its zone/territory.

Looking in the DDBB i see that the field comp_secterr uses the entry type with id 53 (Entry type Territory) with this SQL

`SELECT * FROM Custom_Edits WHERE ColP_ColName LIKE ('comp_secterr');`

but when creaing a new field, in the select, there is not option to choose the Entry Type 53

```
<select class="EDIT" size="1" name="entrytype" id="entrytype" onchange="document.EntryForm.hiddenmode.value=1;document.EntryForm.submit();"><option value="15">Texto con búsqueda de casilla de verificación</option><option value="25">Producto</option><option value="27">Selección inteligente</option><option value="28">Selección múltiple</option><option value="42">Fecha sólo</option><option value="51">Divisa</option><option value="56">Selección de búsqueda avanzada</option><option value="57">Minutos</option><option value="59">Símbolos de las monedas</option><option value="63">Selección de grupo de usuarios</option><option value="10" selected="">Texto</option><option value="44">Procedimiento almacenado</option><option value="45">Casilla</option><option value="50">Número de teléfono</option><option value="11">Texto MultiLínea</option><option value="12">Dirección de correo electrónico</option><option value="13">URL WWW</option><option value="21">Selección</option><option value="22">Selección de usuario</option><option value="23">Selección de Equipo</option><option value="31">Número entero</option><option value="32">Numérico</option><option value="41">Fecha y hora</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry Type 53 is reserved for Territory fields, but is not accessible via the front-end. To use it, you need to update the Custom_Edits table directly using a query similar to this:

```
UPDATE custom_Edits SET colp_entrytype = 53 WHERE ...
```

Make sure you do a full metadata refresh after as well.

While it is not absolutely necessary, it is also good for consistency to name Territory fields _secterr (E.g. comp_secterr)

Six Ticks Support